# No module named 'kivymd' when running app on android phone

Tags: python, android, kivymd

I have written an app that works well on my desktop. I deployed the app on the phone (android) using the following command:

> buildozer android debug deploy run

Unfortunately the app crashes on start, with the following error:

> 09-23 15:36:08.878 27484 27540 I python  : Traceback (most recent call last): 
> 09-23 15:36:08.878 27484 27540 I python  :   File "/home/.../.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1, in  
> 09-23 15:36:08.879 27484 27540 I python  : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd'
> 09-23 15:36:08.879 27484 27540 I python  : Python for android ended.

My code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class DashBoard(Screen):
    pass

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Something'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')

MyApp().run()
```

I really do not understand this error, as the app is working perfectly fine on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. Need to edit `buildozer.spec` file:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd
```

...and add 'kivymd'